# Is it haram to develope a app for gambling for a client?

Tags: halal-haram, software

Assalamu Alaikum,
I am a software developer. I recently got a job offer from a client to develop a gambling app(illegal by local law as well). I won't be promoting or using this application. I will only be just creating the app and handing it over to the client. is this haram?

Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is haram to assist in doing a haram act.

> #### ولا تعاونوا على الإثم والعدوان
>
> Do not cooperate in sin and transgression
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:2](http://quran.com/5/2)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it. I decided to drop the project. May Allah guid us in the right way

Answer (score 0):

It is haram to develop an app for gambling. Gambling is prohibited in Islam, so developing an application that would facilitate it is also not allowed.

In Quran, Allah (SWT) mentions gambling as one of the things that He has made haram:

> “…O you who believe, intoxicants, and **gambling**, sacrificing for idols, and divination are an abomination of Satan’s handiwork. Avoid it so that you may be successful.” (Quran:5:90)

Even if you don't promote or advertise gambling, you're still doing something haram, which is creating the platform for gambling.

However, if you don't do it someone else will, but the money you earn from it will not be halal. Hence, it's better to find an alternate way of earning money. Being an app developer is a noble profession, so it's better to develop apps that will benefit society.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it. I decided to drop the project. May Allah guide us in the right way